# how does the getOutputStream() of Socket work?

Tags: java, sockets

```
  { Socket s = new Socket("xxx.xx.xx.xx",10004);

    BufferedReader bufr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

    BufferedReader bufIn  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    String line = null;     
    while((line=bufr.readLine())!=null){
         if("over".equals(line))
             break;

         out.println(line);

         String upperStr = bufIn.readLine();
         System.out.println(upperStr);
    }

    s.close();}
```

so does the **out.println(line);** mean 1. the string which was entered will appear on the screen and 2.the content will be sent to the server socket at the same time?  Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `out` is a `PrintWriter`, but that doesn't mean that its something that will be printed on the screen. In this case, you gave it something that is the output stream of a socket, so it will print a line to the socket. If you want it to appear on the screen as well, you'll have to call something like `System.out.println(line)` as well.

Comment: I see! It's `PrintWriter.println()`. I'm kind of mixing it up with `System.out.println()`.   Thanks a lot  :)  and it's my first time to ask question here, and I dont know how to give you some reputations.....  I'm working on it

Comment: You're welcome of course. Don't forget to accept the answer on stackoverflow you feel answers your question best. Welcome to SO :)